# Taking user input of an integer that can only be limited 1 digit

Tags: c++

i'm currently learning c++ and have a project that I'm currently working on. My program in its entirety is to randomize 3 numbers from values 0-9 or set them myself. I was able to get the randomize numbers to work but not the setting of numbers myself. The issue being that when i tried to have the numbers as the int data type it produced 3 numbers for one input. It should be that x = 1, y = 2, z =3.... vales are: 123. To counter this issue I made the data type a character instead but it bugs me that random numbers are int values and my set numbers are char values. This is my current code below:

```
if ( userInput == 's') {
    cout << "Enter three distinct digits each in the range 0..9 (e.g. 354)";
    char num1 = ' ';
    char num2 = ' ';
    char num3 = ' ';
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
    cout << endl << "Values to guess are: " << num1 << num2 << num3;
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what it is you're looking for? Are you looking to read in 3 digits into 3 integers or 3 digits into a single integer / numeric type?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you understand better what you're looking for.

Consider for example using:

```
int x;
cin >> x;  // read an integer from the standard input stream (ignoring initial white space)
```

This will read a single integer from standard in, while

```
char c;
cin >> c;  // read a character from standard input stream (ignoring initial white space)
```

read a single character from standard in (generally an ASCII character value).

If you have the following in standard input:

```
354
```

the first will finish with `x = 354` and the second with `c = '3' // = 51`.

From my understanding you want to read 3 digits from standard in and store them in 3 separate numeric data types. You can do this using the following code:

```
uint8_t get_digit() {
    char c;
    cin >> c;                        // read a single non-whitespace character
    if (! is_digit(c) ) return -1;   // Error did not read a digit return bogus number
    return (uint8_t)(c - '0');       // convert ascii digit to number and return value
}
```

This code will read a single character and check if it was a digit, if not it returns a bogus result (`-1`) othewise it returns the numeric value of the digit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This ended up working perfectly for my project.